# Why is the gradient computed with GradientTape wrong in this case (using tfp.vi.monte_carlo_variational_loss)

Tags: keras, gradient, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

The gradients from `tf.GradientTape` seem not to match the correct minimum in the function I'm trying to minimise.

I'm trying to use tensorflowprobability's black-box variational inference (using tf2), with the `tf.GradientTape`, a keras optimizer, calling the `apply_gradients` function. The surrogate posterior is a simple 1d Normal. I'm trying to approximate a pair of normals, see pdist function. For simplicity I just try to optimise the scale parameter.

Current code:

```
from scipy.special import erf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

def pdist(x):
    return (.5/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.exp((-(x+3)**2)/2) + (.5/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.exp((-(x-3)**2)/2)
def logpdist(x):
    logp = np.log(1e-30+pdist(x))
    assert np.all(np.isfinite(logp))
    return logp

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
mu = tf.Variable(0.0,dtype=tf.float64)
scale = tf.Variable(1.0,dtype=tf.float64)
for it in range(100):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        surrogate_posterior = tfd.Normal(mu,scale)
        elbo_loss = tfp.vi.monte_carlo_variational_loss(logpdist,surrogate_posterior,sample_size=10000)
    gradients = tape.gradient(elbo_loss, [scale])
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [scale]))
    if it%10==0: print(scale.numpy(),gradients[0].numpy(),elbo_loss.numpy())
```

Output (showing every 10th iteration):

```
SCALE   GRAD   ELBO_LOSS
1.100, -1.000, 2.697
2.059, -0.508, 1.183
2.903, -0.354, 0.859 <<< (right answer about here)
3.636, -0.280, 1.208
4.283, -0.237, 1.989
4.869, -0.208, 3.021
5.411, -0.187, 4.310
5.923, -0.170, 5.525
6.413, -0.157, 7.250
6.885, -0.146, 8.775
```

For some reason the gradient doesn't reflect the true gradient, which should be about zero around scale=2.74.

Why does the gradient not relate to the actual elbo_loss?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone can elaborate on why the previous implementation failed (and also why it doesn't except, but instead just has the wrong answer). Anyway, I found I could fix it by ensuring that key expressions used the tensorflow maths library and not numpy's. Specifically replacing the two methods above with;

```
def pdist(x):
    return (.5/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * tf.exp((-(x+3)**2)/2) + (.5/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * tf.exp((-(x-3)**2)/2)

def logpdist(x):
    return tf.math.log(pdist(x))
```

The stochastic optimisation now works.

Output:

```
2.020, -0.874, 1.177
2.399, -0.393, 0.916
2.662, -0.089, 0.857
2.761, 0.019, 0.850
2.765, 0.022, 0.843
2.745, -0.006, 0.851
2.741, 0.017, 0.845
2.752, 0.005, 0.852
2.744, 0.015, 0.852
2.747, 0.013, 0.862
```

I'm not going to accept my own answer as I'd be grateful if some answers could be given that give intuition about why this now works and why it failed previously (and why the failure mode wasn't an exception or similar but instead an incorrect gradient).